# How to Set Category Image for WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

How do I set the category image for WordPress? Specifically, I'm looking to update the woocommerce category images with new ones programmatically. I have the ID of the image already uploaded to WordPress, how do I make the connection and replace the existing category image?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress itself does not implements featured images for categories.
The easiest way to achieve your goal is to use [appropriate plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/category+featured+image/). If you already can manage category images, we need to know what plugin/template you are using, because category images can be handled in many different ways by 3rd party software.